# Android: show DialogFragment without (bottom) navigation bar

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I've found a way to prevent showing bottom navigation bar (immersive mode) at the moment of opening a Dialog.

```
    private fun showDialogImmersiveFullscreen(dialog: Dialog) {
        dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        dialog.show()

        // set the dialog to immersive sticky mode
        dialog.window?.decorView?.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        )

        // clear the not focusable flag from the window
        dialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    }
```

It works fine and I don't see the navigation bar at the display transition.

The problems start while trying to achieve it with DialogFragment. At the time I open DialogFragment using the function below, I see the navigation bar appearing for a v. short moment and then it immediately disappears. The idea is not to show it at all...

```
    private fun showDialogImmersiveFullscreen(dialogFragment: DialogFragment?, transaction: FragmentTransaction, tag: String) {
        dialogFragment?.dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        dialogFragment?.show(transaction, tag)
        supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()

        dialogFragment?.dialog?.window?.decorView?.setSystemUiVisibility(
            window.decorView.getSystemUiVisibility()
        )

        // clear the not focusable flag from the window
        dialogFragment?.dialog?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?